# Audio mp3 file Download from url

Tags: objective-c, ios6

How to download mp3 files from url approx 5mb of size in ios 6.0 sdk i am using jsonparser to get response of mp3 files and save in photolibrary ?

Comment: You cannot save an mp3 file as an image. That just doesn't work. At all.

Comment: than what are the alternative's to download audio files and save in documents directory ?

Comment: Save in the music collection?

Comment: how ?? any idea and help for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.pacdv.com/sounds/people_sound_effects/c-c-2.mp3"]; 
NSData *soundData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSString *documents = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]
NSString *filePath = [documents stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];
[soundData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: im using that code my url file size is 60998kb but it downloads only 61kb

Comment: this code is working but if i am changing the url it only downloads 61 kb what im doing wrong?

Comment: Such file is too big to keep in memory. It must be written directly to the filesystem using NSURLConnectionDataDelegate's `connection:didReceiveData:`.

Comment: got it but i want to save my mp3 file to iphone music library ? please help me out